# Empty JSON Return - Symfony3

Tags: php, json, symfony

I am a beginner in PHP & Symfony 3 and I have a problem:
json_encode returns empty objects. You can check the image and code below.

```
/**
 * @Rest\Get("/user")
 */
public function getAction()
{
    $restresult = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findAll();
    if ($restresult === null) {
        return new View("there are no users exist", Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    }

    return new Response(json_encode($restresult), Response::HTTP_OK);
}
```

[image]

Comment: you can use `JsonResponse` btw, look here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#creating-a-json-response

Answer (score 6):

I think It's because the findAll() method return an array of object, you should personalize your method in the repository to get an array result,

```
public function findAllArray()
 {
     $qb = $this
         ->createQueryBuilder('u')
         ->select('u');
     return $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
 }
```

Another thing, in Symfony you can use New JsonResponse to send Json datas

```
return new JsonResponse($restresult);
```

Comment: and with symfony 3, you can use `return $this->json($restresult)`

Comment: Now another error has appeared.  Unable to find template "" (looked into: C:\xampp\htdocs\my_project_name\app/Resources/views, C:\xampp\htdocs\my_project_name\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig/Resources/views/Form).

Answer (score 3):

Repository method `findAll` returns array of objects. When you use `json_encode` on object with private properties, it returns `{}`, unless you implement [`JsonSerialize` interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php).